# polkadot-apps build working, but failing to run

Tags: polkadot-js, apps

We have a forked apps repo and did an upstream merge recently. It is working fine when running yarn start, but whenever we try to build the code and use that index.html file its failing to run. There is no error on build, but failing after it. https://github.com/availproject/avail-apps
Error is attatched below.

[image: build error]

Comment: are you building using the Docker? how are you providing the `WS_URL` environment variable so it won't be `undefined`?

Comment: Not using docker. Just getting from the build directory which is built later